# cherrypy - serve static files and force content-type

Tags: python, http, cherrypy

I'm building a small web-app with cherrypy.

In this app, I need to serve files in two different ways:

1. serve it with the correct mime type, to embed it in a webpage,
2. serve it with `application/octet-stream` mime type, to force the download.

Currently, I added an exposed method to stream files, one at `/document/xx`, returning the correct mime type, the other one at `/download/xx` with the octet-stream mime type.

But I want to avoid coding this myself. It can only bring bugs and security issues.

tl;dr: **How can I force cherrypy's `tools.staticdir` to force download?**

See the full code of the app on github: https://github.com/aspyct/docrepo (note that it's still using the old 'config.ini' file, no config dictionary).

Answer (score 4):

You can force it by providing `content_types` to the tool, that maps file extensions to MIME types. Like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import os

import cherrypy


path   = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
config = {
  'global' : {
    'server.socket_host' : '127.0.0.1',
    'server.socket_port' : 8080,
    'server.thread_pool' : 8
  },
  '/static' : {
    'tools.staticdir.on'            : True,
    'tools.staticdir.dir'           : os.path.join(path, 'static'),
    'tools.staticdir.content_types' : {'html': 'application/octet-stream'}
  }
}


if __name__ == '__main__':
  cherrypy.quickstart(config = config)
```

If you don't know the extension beforehand, take a look at the tool's [source code](https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/src/27475831e2013d72762af0663b762627dde7bd78/cherrypy/lib/static.py?at=default#cl-268). There's barely two dozen of effective lines of code. Just make your own fine-tuned tool of the purpose.